# Connect Office.js (Excel Add-in) to SQL Server

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-addins

Is it possible to connect to SQL server from modern Excel Add-in?

I need to push data from Excel to table on SQL Server. Previously it was done via ActiveX Object and VBA. I want to use modern approach, and Excel Add-in seems the right path.

I tried the following code, which still uses ActiveX Object, but it seems I cannot access it from JavaScript.

```
 var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
 var connectionstring="connection";
 connection.Open(connectionstring);
 var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
```

Can current task be solved by using Office.js rather than other means (SSIS)?

Comment: Have you tried accessing ODBC rather than ADODB?

Comment: I am using ODBC. The problem is that ActiveXObject is not accessible from Office.js. I assume it is done due to nature of ActiveX. So the question is, are there any alternatives to it

Answer (score 0):

Unlike VBA or VSTO-based solutions, you cannot directly call a database in Office.js

Since Office.js is a Javascript-based solution, you can populate the Excel data into a JSON object and pass that to an intermediate REST API, via AJAX/XMLHttpRequest call. The REST API method will take the JSON data as input and update the table in the database .